# Only one select list works on PHP form

Tags: php

**Disclaimer: It's been a while since I last wrote any code. The quality of my code is likely to be sub-par. You've been warned.**

I have a basic form that's meant to search flat files on our server. The "search engine" I created as two select lists: one for the file names and one for the customer site files come from.

For a reason I can't figure out, whatever option I select from the second select list is never captured when I hit Submit.

However, whatever option I select from the first select list is always captured.

What am I missing? I am sure it's starting right at me.... Any hints welcome. Thank you.

Here's my code:

```
<HTML>
<head><title>SEARCH TOOL - PROTOTYPE</title></head>
<body><h1>SEARCH TOOL - PROTOTYPE</h1>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<fieldset>
<legend>Filename (one item)</legend><select name="DBFilename" id="DBFilename">
<?php $con = mysql_connect("localhost",  "user", "pass"); if (!$con) {  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
mysql_select_db("dev", $con) or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("select distinct filename from search_test");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ ?>    <option value="<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>"><?php echo $row['filename']; ?></option> <?php } mysql_close($con); ?>
</select></fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend>Site (one item)</legend><select name="DBSite" id="DBSite">
<?php $con = mysql_connect("localhost",  "user", "pass"); if (!$con) {    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
mysql_select_db("dev", $con) or die(mysql_error());
$result = mysql_query("select distinct site from search_test");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ ?>        <option value="<?php echo $row['site']; ?>"><?php echo $row['site']; ?></option> <?php } mysql_close($con);
?>
</select></fieldset>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >
<input type="button" value="Reset Form" onClick="this.form.reset();return false;" />
</form>
</body>
</HTML>
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        if (!empty($_POST['DBFilename'])) {doFileSearch();}
                elseif (!empty($_POST['DBSite'])) {doSite();}
}

function doFileSearch() {
$mydir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/filedepot";
$dir = opendir($mydir);
$DBFilename = $_POST['DBFilename'];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
if (!$con) {die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
mysql_select_db("dev", $con) or die("Couldn't select the database.");

$getfilename = mysql_query("select filename from search_test where filename='" . $DBFilename . "'") or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table><tbody><tr><td>Results.</td></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getfilename)) {
                $filename = $row['filename'];
                echo '<tr><td><a href="' . basename($mydir) . '/' . $filename . '"  target="_blank">' . $filename . '</a></td></tr>';
        }
                echo "</table></body>";
}

function doSite() {
$mydir = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/filedepot";
$dir = opendir($mydir);
$DBSite = $_POST['DBSite'];

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "pass");
if (!$con) {die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());}
mysql_select_db("dev", $con) or die("Couldn't select the database.");

$getfilename = mysql_query("select distinct filename from search_test where site='" . $DBSite . "'") or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table><tbody><tr><td>Results.</td></tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getfilename)) {
                $filename = $row['filename'];
                echo '<tr><td><a href="' . basename($mydir) . '/' . $filename . '"  target="_blank">' . $filename . '</a></td></tr>';
        }
                echo "</table></body>";

}
?>
```

Comment: can you put the source of what is created to a paste?

Comment: Yikes. Let me try...that's gonna be bulky.

Comment: dont paste it here. put it to a pastebin and link it here

Comment: Done => http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=mjxkVEmW

Comment: see this demo to see what is posted with the form and go from there: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/ycXBH/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete re-re-write here => http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=qi5F7X2e

There are several problems with my form.

- a) Neither one of my SELECT lists are ever empty.
- b) I never check    for return the values from my functions.

This one is working.

Thanks to all for taking the time.

Answer (score 0):

You have no part of your form with `name='submit'`

There for you will never get into the if statement that says: `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {` because it will **always** be false

Comment: What about `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" >`? Are you saying this is not correct?

Comment: @Chris -- hmmm odd, that does not seem to be submitting. (see my demo on the comment to your OP)

Comment: @Chris also the reset could look like this: `<input type="reset" value="Reset Form" />`

Comment: Complete rewrite here => http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=19eLAiFR. Same problem.Any input welcome.